# standalone pgfplot with extra include in subdirectory -> no output

Tags: pgfplots, standalone

I am trying to generate a pgfplot with data in a textfile as a standalone document.
I am using the 1.2 version of standalone from https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/downloads because it makes the package useable on Windows in the first place. I am not sure why this hasn't found its way to CTAN yet.

My file structure is as follows:

```
/main.tex
/tikzdir/myplot.tex
/tikzdir/plotdata/input_all.txt
```

In `input_all.txt` I have some data:

```
x y u v
1 1 1.0391310000000000269 0.95451609999999997846 
0.96086930000000003727 1.0454840000000000799 1.0099340000000001094 1.0800190000000000623
```

`myplot.tex` is the standalone document that creates the plot

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\begin{document}
\providecommand{\plotdataDir}{plotdata}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table {\plotdataDir/input_all.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`main.tex` includes `myplot.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\providecommand{\plotdataDir}{tikzdir/plotdata}

\begin{figure}
\includestandalone{tikzdir/myplot}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Now, when I compile myplot.tex directly everything works as expected. If I then compile `main.tex`, the created pdf is found and again, everything is fine.

However, if I directly want to compile main.tex then the data in input_all.txt is somehow missing and I get an empty plot without data.
I tried to remedy this by using `\providecommand` to specify `\plotdataDir`, but it didn't help.
There is also no error indicating that the data could not be found, so I'm a bit stumped.

Do you have other tips to handle a situation like this?

Comment: Perhaps a problem with the underscore? You could try `"\plotdataDir/input_all.txt"`.

Comment: I had no problem to compile your file with the standalone version v1.1b (which comes with miktex) after I added `\usepackage{pgfplots}` to the main file (and naturally used `--shell-escape`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions: I tried your suggestions: 1) removing the underscore and adding quotes: no effect. 2) already using shell-escape (Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex). 3) adding pgfplots also did not help.

Let me reiterate that the issue is not that it won't compile, but that the plot is empty (no data) if I only compile the main document.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue which is not reproducible.


Comment: I wrote a little enhancement and posted it on bitbucket at the standalone page. Mybe that might help. https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues/41/automated-path-for-pgfplots-grafics-with